# ¿Cómo puedo dar nombre a las leyendas, en este ejemplo de Bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, bokeh

He desarrollado este script en Bokeh.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import pandas_bokeh
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()  # salida al notebook

msft = pdr.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', "2016-1-4", "2021-3-30")
datos = msft[["Close"]]

# Calcular las medias móviles
# Doble de cruces de medias móviles de 50 y 200 días
SMA50 = datos["Close"].rolling(50).mean().dropna()
SMA200 = datos["Close"].rolling(200).mean().dropna()
    
# Crear el DataFrame valor- medias móviles
dfs = [datos, SMA50, SMA200 ]
dfs = iter(dfs)
val_SMA = next(dfs)
for df_ in (dfs):
    val_SMA = val_SMA.merge(df_, left_index = True, right_index = True)

val_SMA .plot_bokeh.line(
    figsize=(800, 450),
    title="Valor seleccionado vs medias móviles SMA50, SMA200",
    xlabel="Fecha",
    ylabel="Precios en €",
    yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ylim=(200, 350),
    xlim=("2016", "2021"),
    colormap=["red", "blue", "green"],
    plot_data_points=True,
    plot_data_points_size=0.8)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que, en la gráfica, quisiera mostrar, en lugar de **Close_X** y **Close_y**, **SM50** y **SM200** respectivamente.

He probado añadiendo  **legend_label= ["Close, "SM50, "SM200"]** y me devuelve un error advirtiendo que no admite listas.

Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción más simple es renombrar las columnas del dataframe. Puedes hacerlo como parte del comando `plot`, encadenando después la llamada a `.plot()`. El renombrado no afecta de forma permanente al dataframe.

Es decir:

```
(val_SMA.rename(columns={"Close_x": "SM50", "Close_y": "SM200"})
  .plot_bokeh.line(
    figsize=(800, 450),
    title="Valor seleccionado vs medias móviles SMA50, SMA200",
    xlabel="Fecha",
    ylabel="Precios en €",
    yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ylim=(200, 350),
    xlim=("2016", "2021"),
    colormap=["red", "blue", "green"],
    plot_data_points=True,
    plot_data_points_size=0.8)
)
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Para que tenga en cuenta la variable nom_val, renombro como sigue: (val_SMA.rename(columns={nom_val +"_x": "SM50", nom_val+"_y": "SM200"})